Task with name 'package' not found in root project 'DecoderISO8583'
I'm trying to make an executable file (preferable .exe) with Compose Desktop and Kotlin Multiplatform according to this source.

build.gradle.kts:

import org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.application.dsl.TargetFormat
import org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.8.21"
    id("org.jetbrains.compose") version "1.6.11"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
    google()
}

kotlin {
    jvm {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "17"
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
                implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.11.0")
            }
        }
    }
}

compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"

        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Exe)
            windows {
                packageVersion = "1.0.0"
                exePackageVersion = "1.0.0"
                installationPath = "${System.getenv("USERPROFILE")}\\DecoderISO8583"
            }
        }
    }
}

// Task to copy the "packager" folder
val copyPackagerFolder by tasks.register<Copy>("copyPackagerFolder") {
    from("src/main/resources/packager") {
        include("**/*.json")
    }

    into("${System.getenv("USERPROFILE")}\\DecoderISO8583\\packager")

    doFirst {
        val installationDir = file("${System.getenv("USERPROFILE")}\\DecoderISO8583")
        if (!installationDir.exists()) {
            installationDir.mkdirs()
        }
        val packagerDir = file("${System.getenv("USERPROFILE")}\\DecoderISO8583\\packager")
        if (!packagerDir.exists()) {
            packagerDir.mkdirs()
        }
    }
}

// Ensure the custom task runs after packaging the distribution
tasks.named("package") {
    finalizedBy(copyPackagerFolder)
}


settings.gradle.kts:

- pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
    }

    plugins {
        id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm").version("1.8.21") // Match the version used in build.gradle.kts
        id("org.jetbrains.compose").version("1.6.11") // Use Compose plugin
    }
}

rootProject.name = "DecoderISO8583"


gradle.properties:

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
kotlin.code.style=official
kotlin.version=1.8.21 // Match the Kotlin version used in build.gradle.kts
compose.version=1.6.11
kotlin.compiler.execution.strategy=in-process
org.gradle.warning.mode=all

When I try to make an executable file according with Compose Desktop tasks showed in these images:


I get lots of times this issue:

Build file 'C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\xxxxxxx\DecoderXXXXXXX\build.gradle.kts' line: 69


Task with name 'package' not found in root project 'DecoderISO8583'.



Try:



Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

It doesn't matter the Compose Desktop task name, I get the same error with different task name.
My objective is to make a .exe with a linked external folder called "packager" which it could work very well during execution of program.
If you can be specified and detailed. I thank you a lot of.
I expect a solution of this issue that I have lots of times to find the solution. I'd like the explanation and the code if it's possible
